# Why doesn't this code work? Combination of for and if for a "test" login page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make some kind of login page (I don't care about security or some sort. This is a test, and I'm not even that advanced of a coder. And I'm struggling with the coding. I want to make it as:

```
    If the username was filled in as "Ardent" and the password as "1", 
        Say something like "Welcome!"
    If the username or(and) the password are(is) incorrect, 
        alert("The username and password is incorrect."); 
and make it loop, leading to asking for username and password again.
```

So, this is what I coded (I could not find out how this can work, so I don't even have the basic structure of it).

```
for([id == prompt("What is your ID?"), password == prompt("What is your password?")]; 
     id == "Ardent" || password == "1" ;) {

    prompt("What is your ID?");
    prompt("What is your password?");
    if(id == "Ardent" || password == "1") {
        alert("Welcome back!");
    }
}
```

Thank you! 
Sorry if it is actually a complete mess :(
I'm so bad at coding and I'm just a beginner.

Comment: What error message are you getting in the console? You should be getting a syntax error that tells you pretty much where the error is. `==` is an equality operator, not assignment.

Comment: Code and Algorithm indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with very clear code as per below.

```js
while(true){
    var username = prompt("What is your username");
    var password = prompt("What is your password");
  
    if(username == "Ardent" && password == "1"){
       alert("Welcome");
        break;
    }
    else{
       alert("Try again");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: An infinite loop might be annoying though. ;-)

Comment: Supposing the user manages to guess the value of two strings… :-(

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to write with "for" statement, or a way to stop the while loop if selected "cancel" in the prompt?

Comment: Welcome!.. Simply you can add `if(!username) break` and `if(!password) break` after each `prompt()` respectively

Answer (score 0):

Javascript 'prompts' return a `String` or `false` if empty, so a variable has to be assigned like so...

```
var id = prompt("What is your ID?");
var password = prompt("What is your password?");
if (id == "Ardent" || password == "1") {
    alert("Welcome back!");
}
```

As far as I can tell from the code example provided the 'for-loop' is superfluous to requirements.

For completeness, it is best to check that the required `String` is actually returned from a prompt() before proceeding, so something like this is usually undertaken...

```
/* declare variables before setting */
var id, password;

/* prompt for id with default string */
id = prompt(
    'What is your ID?', 
    'Enter ID here...'
);

/* check if correct value is returned */
if (id === 'Ardent') {
    /* prompt for password with default string */
    password = prompt(
        'What is your password?', 
        'Enter PASSWORD here...'
    );

    /* check if correct value is returned */
    if (password === '1') {
        alert('Welcome Back!');
    } else {
        /* handle incorrect password */
    }

} else {
    /* handle incorrect id  */
}
```

I hope that helps.

- [See MDN for more info on prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Me too:-

```
do {
    var id = prompt("What is your ID?");
    var password = prompt("What is your password?");
} while (id != "Ardent" && password != "1");
alert("Welcome back");
```

If you are on Firefox press Ctrl+Shift+I to open the Developer Console and see syntax errors in your javascript code.

More on [do..while loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)